# "Teams Free" No Longer Supporting Teams/Channels?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, microsoft-teams, subscriptions

I created a new teams account on this site: https://www.microsoft.com/en-ww/microsoft-teams/free and chose "For work and organizations".

When I start the app (regardless of desktop or web app) it only shows "Activity", "Chat", "Meet" and "Calendar" on the left side, but "Teams" is missing.
I repeated the process with 2 more accounts, tried incognito browser tabs and so on, but to no avail.

Has the "Teams" functionality been removed from free accounts or can it be activated somehow?

Comment: Check detailed comparison of Microsoft Teams plans & see if "Teams" functionality is available with free account or not: https://www.microsoft.com/en-ww/microsoft-teams/compare-microsoft-teams-options?activetab=pivot%3Aprimaryr1

Comment: Thanks, I actually came across that site during my research but couldn't find anything conclusive. Perhaps I'm reading it wrong, are you sure that information is contained in there?